# Are there some standard sizes when it comes to square page layouts?

Tags: page-layout, print-design, design-principles

I am designing this luxury product catalogue and I was thinking to make the pages square so it would somehow be a little more unique and stuff...

The way I have it set up now is 8in x 8in(about 20cm x 20cm). So it kind of fits on an A4 page width.

Is that good? Is there such a thing as standard sizes when it comes to square page layouts ? Or is it ok as long as it fits whitin a standard(A5/A4/A3/A2/B5 etc) ?

Im thinking to make it as easy as posible for the printers...

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/what-size-should-i-make-my-gatefold-brochure

Answer (score 3):

Printers can print on most any size. There are presses designed for 'one sheets' that tend to be smaller but if you're printing a luxury product catalog, I'm assuming you're using a rather large offset press that will be printing large signatures (multiple pages of your catalog printed together on one large sheet).

If you're trying to make it easy for the printers, then you need to direct this question their way. They'll be able to help you figure out the most economical size to be doing everything with.

The other big consideration you'll likely want to ponder is how are these going to be mailed and to where are they being mailed to? A difference in an inch or cm here or there can have a huge effect on postal rates.

Comment: A great outline of where to start on this kind of project. "Ask your printer" should be engraved on every designer's monitor. (Well, not on the actual screen...)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @DA01's excellent answer, you will want to also ask your local post office what dimensions are allowable at bulk rates and what triggers the more expensive ones. Here in America, it doesn't take much for the mail rates to get expensive when stepping out of "standard" sizes. I don't see many square pieces in my mail and there may well be a reason for that. Postal sizes and rates are another one those "where the rubber meets the road" issues for graphic designers. Printers may not have a restriction but a postal service can (and usually do).

Comment: hmz... never thought about that. i will keep it in mind from now on before starting a project. important stuff to ask BEFORE you start something like this. it will also have a spiral binding, that might also be an issue with postal services...

Comment: Spiral binding might (and most likely will) require the catalog to be shrink-wrapped or packaged before shipping. Definitely speak to your local postal rep or a packaging company.